# How many classes per module

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox-addon-sdk

**How many classes/functions are best put into a module** (which is later `require`d, f.ex. by [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), the [Mozilla addon loader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/_loader), ...)?

As the module seems to be imported wholesale (contrary to f.ex. Python, where you can do `from module import class`), would it be best to keep them as small as possible? Any other guidelines?

What is the best practice?

(There are similar questions about [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312642/how-many-classes-per-package-methods-per-class-lines-per-method) (which recommends ["the more granular class layout you have, the better"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17927021/1587329)),  [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061930/python-one-class-per-module-and-packages) (which allows for more objects and states ["Python is not C#/Java. Trying to bend it to make it look like `$other_language` will cause frustration and poor user experience"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8062064/1587329)) , etc, but nothing JavaScript-specific appeared.)

---

Maybe these questions were old enough to pass the site standards then. Nowadays, it might be really too broad for some.

Comment: As is, this question is too broad. A complete answer would be well too long for the Stackoverflow format.

Comment: Recommendations for off-site ressources are off topic on Stackoverflow. I don't think this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow as a site.

Comment: @Magisch: @ Arnaud has answered this, so it should not be too broad. Similarly, the Python, Java, ... questions have usual-length answers, too.

Comment: as many as it needs and not a single line more.

Comment: Agreed with user, this is a legitimate question when using RequireJS, and is not too broad since it accepts a concise answer. The answer is taken from my personal experience of RequireJS during several years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally do the following when using RequireJS:

- One class per module
- Module file named after the class name

This allows for easy maintenance, plus dynamic loading of the needed classes.

Only drawback could be the amount of files, but you can bundle the ones most used later using RequireJS [optimization features](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).